# Autogenerate of years within a span of numbers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Yep, it may sound confusing so I thought i'll explain the problem more detailed.

Now I'm not asking for a solution of what, I just need to know if it is possible. I tried searching the net for answer but it seems that those sites I visited does not fulfill the answer I need to see.

Is it possible to display year using php/html without writing the years in the code behind like the below

```
<label for="year" style="padding-right: 10px;margin-top:7px;">Year</label>
          <select name="year" id="year" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                <option value="0">Choose Year</option>
                <option value="1990">1990</option>
                <option value="1991">1991</option>
                <option value="1992">1992</option>
                <option value="1993">1993</option>
                <option value="1994">1994</option>
                <option value="1995">1995</option>
                <option value="1996">1996</option>
                <option value="1997">1997</option>
                <option value="1998">1998</option>
                <option value="1999">1999</option>
                <option value="2000">2000</option>
                <option value="2001">2001</option>
                <option value="2002">2002</option>
                <option value="2003">2003</option>
                <option value="2004">2004</option>
                <option value="2005">2005</option>
                <option value="2006">2006</option>
                <option value="2007">2007</option>
                <option value="2008">2008</option>
                <option value="2009">2009</option>
                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                <option value="2017">2017</option>
                <option value="2018">2018</option>
                <option value="2019">2019</option>
                <option value="2020">2020</option>
          </select>
```

What I want to know if is it possible to show the year without the above code like for example display 2004 to 2024. Now today is 2014. When year changes to 2015 then year range will be 2005 to 2025.

Is this possible?

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really complicated. Just get your current year and then subtract 100 from it. Then use a for loop that starts with your start year and ends when it reaches the current year.

```
$last  = date("Y");
$start = $year - 100;
for ($i = $start; $i <= $last; $i++) {
    echo '<option value="' . $i. '">' . $i. '</option>';
}
```

You can improve upon this by adding new lines, not embedding your HTML in your PHP, etc.

Comment: Now, why did I have a feeling you'd be here tonight ;) Must be my *spider sense*.

Comment: Ironically I am arachnophobic so the *opposite* should be occurring. ;)

Comment: I too, but to a certain extent. I find them quite fascinating.

Comment: Actually I'm confused if arachnophobic  or no since I can handle little spiders but can't take big ones. Tickles my hand. :D

Comment: I'm okay with daddy long legs. All of the others make me, um, look ridiculous at time...

Comment: @Dodgeball The little ones can be just as nasty. Fear the smaller scorpion as opposed to a bigger scorpion too ;)

Comment: @ahaha......never feared the scorpion...Actually one of my favorite delicacy is the scorpion soup...its like eating breaded shrimps.

Comment: @Dodgeball *Hm...*, food that can potentially bite back. I think I'll stick with Gaspacho. ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think Gaspacho is just an appetizer, what about for the main course?

Comment: @Dodgeball Canelloni with a side order of whatever the Chef wants to throw in (and not throw UP), then the richest chocolate cake available known to man. ;)